# Pandas Groupby Sample on a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to randomly sample a *relatively* large dataset (consists of 90 [mn] or so data points)

I would like to sample the dataset based on column "a" (which has roughly 100k unique values) with each a having a different n value.

I know something like this exists:

```
df.groupby("a").sample(n=1, random_state=1)
```

But this does not take into different n values into account.

Next thought was filtering df by a then sampling after filtering on a loop ('m' is unique values of 'a' I am sampling):

```
filter_df = df.loc[(df['a'] == f)]

filter_df = filter_df.sample(n=m, random_state=6)
```

To add another layer of potential complication, I would like to sample the data if it exceeds total number of samples per group "a", to use `replace = True` otherwise if the sample is larger `replace = False` so that I am picking as many unique rows as possible.

So, within a for loop that is enumerated (e.g. 4 separate lists that's 100k long including column "a"'s unique values lets call it variable 'kk' which is an integer:

```
if kk >= m:
        filter_df = filter_df.sample(n=m, random_state=6)
        print("sampling okay")
        test["flag"] = "ok"
    else:
        filter_df = filter_df.sample(n=m, random_state=6,replace=True)
```

Was used, then concat was used at the end to combine.

This is the basic idea, and code works fine however, the performance is sub-optimal.
Was wondering if there is a vectorized potential solution I could use.

Just for brevity the number of samples "m" is count of first df:

| `a` | `count` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `1` |
| `2` | `3` |
| `3` | `2` |

original df I am trying to sample from:

| a | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |
| 3 | g |

Desired sampled output (of course the sampled x will be "random"):

| `a` | `x` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |
| 3 | g |

Comment: `sample` will do everything you are asking. You may want to consider separating your filter logic from your sample logic, so you produce a filtered `df` first, then sample it. Review the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for `sample`, and you'll find you are not using `sample` correctly.

Comment: thanks for your comment. sample only takes a single value of n, however I am trying to extract different values of n per each group "a". (over 100k different groups with different n values, which makes the grouby sample an issue), which I set a loop to go through.
I am already filtering the data before sampling as mentioned above, however issue is the speed at this stage. 
unless I've understood your answer incorrectly...

Comment: Look into PySpark Window functions. It will let you create a "window" into each group of "a". You can then rank items in the window, and extract x number of items per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary from the first dataframe and create custom grouping function:

```py
def get_sample(df, dct, random_state):
    a = df["a"].iat[0]
    n = dct.get(a)

    if n is None:
        return

    return df.sample(n=n, random_state=random_state, replace=len(df) <= n)


dct = df1.set_index("a")["count"].to_dict()

out = df2.groupby("a", group_keys=False).apply(get_sample, dct=dct, random_state=6)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   a  x
0  1  a
3  2  d
4  2  e
4  2  e
5  3  f
6  3  g
```

---

Input dataframes:

```
# df1
   a  count
0  1      1
1  2      3
2  3      2

# df2
   a  x
0  1  a
1  1  b
2  1  c
3  2  d
4  2  e
5  3  f
6  3  g
```

Comment: this worked out brilliantly in terms of speeds. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(df.groupby('a', as_index = False)
  .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n := df1.loc[df1['a'] == x['a'].iloc[0],'count'].iloc[0], 
                             replace = n > x['a'].size, random_state=6))
  .reset_index(drop = True))
   a  x
0  1  a
1  2  d
2  2  e
3  2  e
4  3  g
5  3  f
```

---

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3}, 'x': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g'}})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'count': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2}})
```